# How to custom Edittext listener

Tags: android, android-edittext

How can I use the edittext listener to prevent the user from entering special characters (&%+?@...etc) and also prevent the user from entering numbers, finally allow user to enter only letters (A B C ...)

Comment: Please accept some answers from your old questions. People are more likely to give you answers when you give them credit for their work. :)

Comment: @Dev: Check the green tick to the left of the appropriate answer.

Comment: On the left of each answer are the rating elements. Below that should be a small "check" sign to mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [`EditText.setFilters()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setFilters%28android.text.InputFilter%5B%5D%29). This allows you to specify one or more instances of [`InputFilter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html) for an `EditText`. These filter certain characters from the input, as the name suggest. There are a lot of prebuild ones (see "know subclasses" at the top of the class documentation), but you may also implement your own by extending the `InputFilter` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use add TextWatcher (link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to your EditText (link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) and implement the three provided methods in order to control the input from the user and perform any operation you want.

Comment: Could you please tell me how in code , I'm beginner in android development